# How to split datatable row in to multiple rows based on character split in .net

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a datatable as shown below

```
Dosage  Drug            Patient
-----------------------------------
  25    Indocin         David
  50    Enebrel,Crozine Sam
  10    Hydralazine     Christoff
  21    Combivent       Janet
 100    Dilantin        Melanie
```

which should be converted in to as shown below based on comma split

```
Dosage  Drug            Patient
------------------------------
  25    Indocin         David
  50    Enebrel         Sam
  50    Crozine         Sam
  10    Hydralazine     Christoff
  21    Combivent       Janet
 100    Dilantin        Melanie
```

I did following code which is not giving the expected result. Can somebody suggest an answer?

```
private static void ProcessDatatable(DataTable dt)
{
    DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();

    IEnumerable<string[]> allRowValues = dt.AsEnumerable()
                                           .Select(r => r.Field<string>(1).Split(','));

    dtnew = allRowValues.ToDataTable();
}
```

Extension method:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, string tableName)
{
    DataTable tbl = ToDataTable(collection);
    tbl.TableName = tableName;

    return tbl;
}

public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    Type t = typeof(T);

    PropertyInfo[] pia = t.GetProperties();

    // Create the columns in the DataTable
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pia)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, pi.PropertyType);
    }

    // Populate the table
    foreach (T item in collection)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        dr.BeginEdit();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in pia)
        {
             dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(item, null);
        }

        dr.EndEdit();

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer as per comment you added under another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only barely comfortable with C# so I had to do this the old fashioned way but it works.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataTable dt;
    private DataTable dtExpanded;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadTable();
        LoadExpandedTable();
    }
    //Dosage Drug            Patient
   private void LoadTable()
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From DrugDoses", cn))
            {
                cn.Open();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
    private void LoadExpandedTable()
    {
        dtExpanded = new DataTable();
        dtExpanded.Columns.Add("Dose");
        dtExpanded.Columns.Add("Drug");
        dtExpanded.Columns.Add("Patient");
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            string s = (string)r["Drug"];
            if(s.Contains(","))
            {
                string[] splitName = s.Split(',');
                foreach (string drug in splitName)
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dtExpanded.NewRow();
                    newRow.ItemArray = new Object[] { r["Dosage"], drug , r["Patient"]};
                    dtExpanded.Rows.Add(newRow);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dtExpanded.Rows.Add(r.ItemArray);
            }

        }
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dtExpanded;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you think you want is this:

```
IEnumerable<object[]> allRowValues = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(dataRow =>
        dataRow.Field<string>(1).Split(',').Select(drug => new[] { dataRow[0], drug, dataRow[2] }));
```

But what you really want is this:

```
IEnumerable<Record> allRowValues = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(dataRow => new Record(dataRow))
    .SelectMany(record => record.SplitDrugs());

// ...

public class Record
{
    public int Dosage { get; }
    public string Drug { get; }
    public string Patient { get; }

    public Record(int dosage, string drug, string patient)
    {
        Dosage = dosage;
        Drug = drug;
        Patient = patient;
    }

    public Record(DataRow dataRow)
        : this((int)dataRow["Dosage"], (string)dataRow["Drug"], (string)dataRow["Patient"])
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<Record> SplitDrugs()
    {
        return Drug.Split(',').Select(drug => new Record(Dosage, drug, Patient));
    }
}
```

Short explanation: with a fancy LINQ you are trying to solve just too many problems of the world liek extracting information from data table, processing rows one by one, applying bussiness logic and merging the result to new data table. That is a good way how to write error-prone, unreadable, untestable, unstable and unmaintanable code.

Incomplete list of people who will eventually thank you for chosing the second option:

- **your future self**
- your teammates
- your code reviewer
- unit test writer
- end users
- your teacher (if assignment)
- SO community

While I'm at it I'll save you some time debugging your transformation of `allRowValues` (which in your case is of type `IEnumerable<string[]>`) back to `DataTable`. If you think it will contain 3 columns, then you're wrong. Instead, it will contain columns like `Length`, `LongLength`, `Rank`, ... Have a look at [properties Array class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.8#properties) to figure out why.

### Edit

OP has refined the original intent in a comment under another answer.

> ... , but i just posted a prototype of datatable,infact actually 180 columns are there.DO i need to add all 180 columns manually in newRow.ItemArray, when there is a split of comma seperated values???Any easier way?

Yes, there is an easier way. Involving generics you can expand the usage beyond this limited use case:

```
// extension method
public static DataTable ExpandColumn<T>(this DataTable dataTable, string columnName,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> expandField)
{
    var clonedDataTable = dataTable.Clone();
    var columnIndex = dataTable.Columns.IndexOf(columnName);
    var column = dataTable.Columns[columnIndex];
    foreach (var dataRow in dataTable.AsEnumerable())
    {
        var valueToExpand = dataRow.Field<T>(column);
        var expandedValues = expandField(valueToExpand);
        var originalValues = dataRow.ItemArray;
        foreach (var value in expandedValues)
        {
            originalValues[columnIndex] = value;
            clonedDataTable.Rows.Add(originalValues);
        }
    }
    return clonedDataTable;
}

// usage
var dataTableNew = dataTable.ExpandColumn<string>("Drug", drug => drug.Split(','));
```

The above extension method clones `DataTable` instance by copying original rows and expands values in specified column by applying `expandField` function for each value.

I'd still like you to learn lesson from what I wrove above the edit and think twice about your design.